# what raster format for r.los in qgis

Tags: qgis, plugins

What raster format should I use to create viewsheds in QGIS using the grass r.los plugin? 
I am using the Ordnance Survey Opendata DTM (tried both ascii and shapefile formats) and srtm geotiffs but when I run r.los I can't select an input raster - does that mean the raster is the wrong format?

Comment: In case you didn't know, you first have to import the ascii or geotiff into GRASS with r.in.gdal, r.in.xyz, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It works here with OS OpenData *.asc rasters. QGIS Master, Ubuntu 12.04 running GRASS r.los from the Sextante toolbox. N.